# Facebook Page Realtime Update callback content

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, real-time-updates

I'm having issues with Facebook Realtime updates.  I'm on Ruby using the Koala gem for FB graph API access. I subscribe to a feed for a page and get the callback correctly but the data I get is not in the format specified in the documentation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#realtime

What I get is.

```
{"object"=>"page", "entry"=>[{"id"=>"539998079357096", "time"=>1363046743, "changed_fields"=>["feed"]}]}
```

I was expecting something like.

```
{
  "object": "page",
  "entry": [
    {
      "id": "408518775908252",
      "time": 1360637562,
      "changes": [
        {
          "field": "feed",
          "value": {
            "item": "post",
            "verb": "add",
            "post_id": 410746582352138
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Hello @user2158942 can you give me some hint about how subscribe to a page/feed? I created the app, is configured to get Real Time Updates from "object:page" and "fields:feed", i added it to my page as a Tab, and still got nothing.

By the way, for everything that i read until now, the data that facebook will send to you is correct. The information about the post will not be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Besides whitespacing, what you're receiving looks like it's been parsed by JSON.

Look for something like 
`JSON.parse(request.body.read)`
in your code and inspect request.body before it gets parsed.